# Different line styles for different sections of a plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Is there a way to apply different line styles for sections of a plot?

As an example, for having a part of a graph `dotted` as shown below, I currently add three separate plots:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}
[ xmin=0, xmax=10,
  ymin=0, ymax=10,
]

\addplot[domain=0:6] {.5*\x + 2};
\addplot[domain=6:8,dotted] {.5*\x + 2};
\addplot[domain=8:10] {.5*\x + 2};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis} 
[ xmin=0, xmax=10,
  ymin=0, ymax=10,
]

\def\clippath{(6,0)rectangle(8,10)}

\addplot+ [domain=0:10,mark=none,black,postaction={decorate,white,dashed,decoration={soft clip,soft clip path={\clippath},},},] {.5*\x + 2};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It paints over the curve with a white dashed line inside the rectangle defined as `clipppath`. This is not exactly, what you have requested, but maybe it will do the job for you.